# why print() function gives blank list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run this code but I got nothing.Can anyone tell me why It gives nothing.

```
   thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
   for x in thislist:
       thislist.append(x.upper())
   print(thislist)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating over a list that you are adding to meaning you will never reach the end of the list since every loop you an an extra item. Instead iterate over a slice of the list

```py
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print(thislist)

for x in thislist[:]:
    thislist.append(x.upper())

print(thislist)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'APPLE', 'BANANA', 'CHERRY']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Code**

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
newlist = []
for x in range(len(thislist)):
   newlist.append(thislist[x].upper())
print(newlist)
```

Happy Learning :)

Comment: Not to be too critical, but in python, whenever you find yourself doing `range(len(some_list))` you are almost always doing it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Because you created an infinite loop.
try this:

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for i in range(len(thislist)):
  thislist[i] = thislist[i].upper()
print(thislist)
```

And you will get:

> ['APPLE', 'BANANA', 'CHERRY']